# Discord.js v12 how to take everyone who is mentioned?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I am working on a command that can take everyone mentioned in the command and gives them each a role.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")) {
    let muteUsers = message.mentions.members (idk this part)
    muteUsers.roles.add(rolewhatever)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `members` and give them the role

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")) {
    message.mentions.members.forEach(member => member.roles.add(rolewhatever))
  }
})
```